# Jquery animation thumbnail slider

Tags: jquery, image, animation, slider

I am trying to build a thumbnail slider(not sure it is the name) exactly like [this](http://www.tn3gallery.com/), but I am stuck since I am not really good at jquery animation API. so far I have this code:
http://jsfiddle.net/bingjie2680/mwxzT/13/, but it is  not working expectedly, can somebody please help me with this, or give me some pointers or links to tutorials of how to implement it. I have searched the internet, couldn't find anything relevant.  thanks for reading.

**update:**
the problem is that when the red box slides, it is not smoothly, and the left side of red box should never moves inside the black box. always align both left and right side with the black box.

Comment: Please specify the specific issues you are having so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Hey bingjie. There are a lot of plug-ins for this. Why don't you just use one of them?

Comment: can you give me a link to that???

Comment: `exactly like this` <-- Then why reinvent the wheel when you could just use it as is?

Comment: that plugin is so big,,,I only need the slider feature, so that I won't get any unused code..keep the code clean..

Comment: kei, reinventing the wheel makes the *wheel* a bit more round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you like this one? :)

[MOUSEMOVE GALLERY SLIDER](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/wdcmV/)

HTML:

```
<div id="mmGallery_container">   
    <div id="mmGallery">
        <img src="image1.jpg" style="height:<!--set first image height-->px;"/>
        <img src="image.jpg"/>
        <img src="image.jpg"/>
        <img src="image.jpg"/>
        <img src="image.jpg"/>
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* ***** mmGallery ***** */   
#mmGallery_container{
    position:relative;
    top:30px;
    z-index:0;
    margin:20px auto;
    /*height: 200px; will be handled by jQuery */
    width:560px;   /*  SET WIDTH!  */
    overflow:hidden;
    -moz-box-shadow:     5px 8px 50px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 8px 50px #000;
    box-shadow:         5px 8px 50px #000;
    border:12px solid #000;
    background:#000;
}
#mmGallery{
    cursor:col-resize;
    position:relative;
}
#mmGallery img{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    // roXon mmGallery

    //####### SETUP SPEED ######//
    mmGalSpeed = 20;              // higher number = slower movements
    //##########################//

    var setHeight = $('#mmGallery img:eq(0)').height();
    $('#mmGallery_container').css({ height: setHeight });

});
$(window).load(function(){
    /*________________mmGallery _________________*/

    sumW = 0;   
    imgH = 0;
    imgH = $('#mmGallery img:eq(0)').height(); 
    $('#mmGallery img').css({ height: imgH });    
    $('#mmGallery_container').css({ height: imgH });

    $('#mmGallery img').each(function(){
        sumW += $(this).width();
        $('#mmGallery').width(sumW);
    });    

    wDiff1 = $('#mmGallery_container').outerWidth(true);
    wDiff2 = $('#mmGallery').width();
    wDiff = (wDiff2/wDiff1)-1;  
    mouseX = 0;
    $("#mmGallery_container").mousemove(function(e) {
    mouseX = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft);      
    });

    var xSlider = $("#mmGallery");
    var posXdec = 0;
    setInterval(function(){     
        posXdec += (mouseX - posXdec) / mmGalSpeed;
        posX = posXdec;

        xSlider.css({marginLeft:  '-'+ (posX * wDiff) +'px' }); // instead 'marginLeft' use 'left' for absolute pos. #mmGallery
    }, 10);

});
```

Comment: Great! Hope it's well commented. It's a nice little script when you remove all those comments. and btw, you can remove `.toFixed(2)` and `Math.round` (leave the rest!)